# Where to configure the org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MdbDelegateWrapper

Tags: jboss, jms, ejb-3.0, message-driven-bean, jboss-mdb

I need to reduce the pool size of an MDB to 5 because it connect to an external resource that is limited in terms of connections. If I have 15 messages in my JMS queue, then only 5 msg are process successfully and the other 10 are waist because of connection error happening in the MDB code.

I show this setup in the Jboss JMX-console:
[image: JMX-console]

I'm using Jboss 4.2.3.  I need to know where I can edit this MaxPoolSize config.  I searched everywhere but haven't found it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess adding the limit in 'instance-pool' in Jboss.xml should do it.

Check this [blog article](http://obiecte.blogspot.com/2007/04/jboss-per-mdb-pool-size.html) and [Jboss docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch5.chapter.html) to see how to use 'instance-pool' and 'strictMaximumSize'